# Fiddler session disappears after being shown

Tags: fiddler

I am tracking an IOS app through fiddler as a proxy. And for some requests from the IOS app, fiddler will display those sessions in a flash and then those sessions are gone. It is against my common sense that why a landed session in fiddler will ever disappear. The only thing I can think of is that the response of the http session is violating the protocol? But the IOS app behaves normally with those http requests and responses.

I did catch some screen shots for the http request while it is being displayed in fiddler, and here is how it looks like for each fiddler column:

```
#:76
Result:-
Protocol:HTTP
Host:184.102.xxx.xx
URL:/someUrl/someHashCode
Body:-1
Caching:
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: This happens to me too, but the client is TortoiseMantis (a TortoiseSVN plugin for integration with Mantis bug tracker) and the server is (obviously) Mantis. The response that flashes up in Fiddler also has Body -1. Any clues? I have no filters in Fiddler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In both cases, the traffic is being hidden by a filter. Click `Help` > `Troubleshoot Filters` and follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric! I do have a "show only the following hosts" filter turned on somehow.